# How to generate a dataset using tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I need a Dataset kind of tensor, shape=[160000, 1, 2], I want to generate 
combination like below, but from 0 to 400

```
[[[0 0]]

[[0 1]]

[[0 2]]

[[0 3]]

[[1 0]]

[[1 1]]

[[1 2]]

[[1 3]]

[[2 0]]

[[2 1]]

[[2 2]]

[[2 3]]]
```

Comment: you can create dataset out of  `Numpy` use TF in following [how-to-generate-a-dataset-using-tensor-in-tensorflow](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/tensorflow-dataset-tutorial/)

Comment: I can't figured it up can you help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a numpy array and create tensor by using it. The following code outputs a tensor of `shape = [160000, 1, 2]` where each value is between `0 to 400`.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
arr = np.random.random_integers(low=0, high=400, size=(160000, 1, 2))
tensor = tf.constant(arr)
```